# Connection GeoDB to ASP.Net web application

Tags: c#, geolocation, arcgis

I have a GeoDB which has the extension **.gdb**. Is there any one who has tried to connect a GeoDB using C# with using ArcGIS SDK?

Comment: When you say "GeoDB", you mean a regular File Geodatabase, right?

Answer (score 2):

The ArcObjects code below requires that you've checked out a license. (How that is done depends on the ArcGIS version you've installed. For example, with ArcGIS 9.3.1, a call to `IAoInitialize.Initialize` was sufficient. In ArcGIS 10, you additionally need to bind to a product first via a call to `ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense`.)

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB;
…

IWorkspaceFactory wsFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();  // (see P.S. below)
IWorkspace ws = wsFactory.OpenFromFile(@"\path\to\your\file.gdb", hWnd);
```

You can then open feature classes, tables, etc. in the File Geodatabase by casting `ws` to `IFeatureWorkspace` and using that interface's methods such as `OpenTable`, `OpenFeatureClass`, etc.

---

> **P.S.:** ESRI actually recommends that workspace factories (being singleton objects) be created with `Activator.CreateInstance` instead of `new`:
>
> ```
> Type wsFactoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");
> IWorkspaceFactory wsFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(wsFactoryType);
> …
> ```
>
> (I hadn't mentioned that earlier because it adds some complexity to a simple code example.)